# CASTING issue with SQL query in Databricks with Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am trying to use the CAST function on a field in SQL to cast a Time field as a string, but I'm getting unexpected errors

The code is as follows:

`select DATE_ADD(cast(LAST_MOD_TIME as STRING) % 100 + CAST(LAST_MOD_TIME AS STRING) / 100 % 100 * 60 + CAST(LAST_MOD_TIME AS STRING) / 10000 * 3600, CAST(LAST_MOD_DATE AS STRING)) from DmWo`

But I'm getting the error:

```
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'date_add((((CAST(CAST(dmwo.`LAST_MOD_TIME` AS STRING) AS DOUBLE) % CAST(100 AS DOUBLE)) + (((CAST(CAST(dmwo.`LAST_MOD_TIME` AS STRING) AS DOUBLE) / CAST(100 AS DOUBLE)) % CAST(100 AS DOUBLE)) * CAST(60 AS DOUBLE))) + ((CAST(CAST(dmwo.`LAST_MOD_TIME` AS STRING) AS DOUBLE) / CAST(10000 AS DOUBLE)) * CAST(3600 AS DOUBLE))), CAST(dmwo.`LAST_MOD_DATE` AS STRING))' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires date type, however, '(((CAST(CAST(dmwo.`LAST_MOD_TIME` AS STRING) AS DOUBLE) % CAST(100 AS DOUBLE)) + (((CAST(CAST(dmwo.`LAST_MOD_TIME` AS STRING) AS DOUBLE) / CAST(100 AS DOUBLE)) % CAST(100 AS DOUBLE)) * CAST(60 AS DOUBLE))) + ((CAST(CAST(dmwo.`LAST_MOD_TIME` AS STRING) AS DOUBLE) / CAST(10000 AS DOUBLE)) * CAST(3600 AS DOUBLE)))' is of double type. argument 2 requires (int or smallint or tinyint) type, however, 'CAST(dmwo.`LAST_MOD_DATE` AS STRING)' is of string type.; line 1 pos 7;
'Project [unresolvedalias(date_add((((cast(cast(LAST_MOD_TIME#88591 as string) as double) % cast(100 as double)) + (((cast(cast(LAST_MOD_TIME#88591 as string) as double) / cast(100 as double)) % cast(100 as double)) * cast(60 as double))) + ((cast(cast(LAST_MOD_TIME#88591 as string) as double) / cast(10000 as double)) * cast(3600 as double))), cast(LAST_MOD_DATE#88590 as string)), None)]
```

Any thoughts on where I might be going wrong with the CAST function?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you're trying to achieve here? I'm bit confused with the weirdly looking query you wrote! Additionally, I also would like you to please format this query properly so that the forum could understand your use case ?

Answer (score -1):

There are several mistakes here:

1. The first argument to DATE_ADD function is the `start_date`, and needs to be a `date` type, but you're passing in the time of the day in seconds based on the logic, and the type is `double` due to the division operator.
2. The second argument to DATE_ADD function is the `num_days` after the starting date and needs to be `int` type. You're passing in the starting date itself as a `string` type.
3. DATE_ADD function returns the date that is `num_days` after `start_date`, but you are adding the date and the time of day counted in seconds. That's not what this function does for you.

A simpler way is to use the `to_timestamp()` function:

```sql
select to_timestamp(concat(LAST_MOD_DATE, LAST_MOD_TIME), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss')
from DmWo
```